# MBProgress HUD with Google calendar

Tags: xcode, calendar, hud

hello guys i'm trying to show mbprogress during my app download google calendars event but i have a problem...if i add mbprogress i can't download events...

here my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    tabella.hidden=YES;

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Attendere prego...";
    HUD.square = NO;
    HUD.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}


- (void)myTask:(id)selector{
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    googleCalendarService = [[GDataServiceGoogleCalendar alloc] init];

    [googleCalendarService setUserAgent:@"xxxxx"];
    [googleCalendarService setUserCredentialsWithUsername:@"xxxxxx"
                                                 password:@"yyyyy"];

    [self refresh];


}

- (void)refresh{



    [data removeAllObjects];
   [googleCalendarService fetchCalendarFeedForUsername:@"xxxxx"
                                               delegate:self
                                      didFinishSelector:@selector( calendarsTicket:finishedWithFeed:error: )];


}
```

problem is that app don't goes to calendarsTicket void